# Rails load some list ob objects to slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

it's my first question in stackoverflow.

In my application i have a real time section, to see the movements of the web. Its an online newspaper and ths section shows: new article, new comment, new vote, new debate.....all what is happening on the web.

I have this code:

```
def index
    @objects = Article.find(:all, :conditions => { :created_at => (Time.now-48.hours)..(Time.now), :published => true })
    @objects = @objects + Debate.find(:all, :conditions => { :created_at => (Time.now-48.hours)..(Time.now), :active => true })
    @objects = @objects + Event.find(:all, :conditions => { :created_at => (Time.now-48.hours)..(Time.now), :active => true })

    @objects = @objects + Comment.find(:all, :conditions => {  :created_at => (Time.now-48.hours)..(Time.now), :active => true })
    @objects = @objects + Vote.find(:all, :conditions => {  :created_at => (Time.now-48.hours)..(Time.now) })

    @objects.sort! {|x,z| x.created_at <=> z.created_at}
    @objects.reverse!

end
```

I load all in the last 48 hours. I've been reading about caching in rails because I think that this isn't my solution.

What can I do to load this list more fast? Because now it takes 7...or 8 seconds...

Thanks for all :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few notes:

1. `find(:all)` is [deprecated](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface). use `where()` instead.
2. instead of doing 5 db calls migrate them into one db call (create a sql query for that if needed).
3. make sure you index the dates columns in your tables.
4. don't sort sort and reverse. instead replace `y <=> x` so it will sort the way you need.

hope it helps..

Comment: OK! 1 is solved. I used where. in the step 2, with the db connections, I cant imagine how to do all connections in only one because there are 5 models. I'm new in rails....sorry...